# teamcity command line interpretter : quotes are replaced

Tags: command, teamcity, quotes

I need to run a simple command line within teamcity

```
FINDSTR /M /N /P /S /R /C:"goto end" D:\blabla\*
```

The double quote are replaced and somehow doubled when teamcity calls the command. The resulting command is

```
cmd.exe /c FINDSTR /M /N /P /S /R "/C:"goto end""
```

Which fails.

How can I prevent this from happening? The value for param `/C` requires a param with double quotes in my case. thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'within teamcity' ? Did you try execute build step with runner 'Command Line'? In this case TeamCity wrap your commands in bat file and this problem should not arise...

Comment: Exactly this is what I ended up doing. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your command in a batch file and call that passing in whatever arguments (if any) you need.

Whenever you do anything like this on windows, always do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

`FINDSTR /M /N /P /S /R /C:"goto end" D:\blabla\*`

Works as-is, in TeamCity 2018.1.3, using a Command Line runner with the above specified in the Custom Script section.